# Error 500 while webscraping with rvest

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to webscrape with the code below, but am getting the following warning message:

> In request_POST(session, url = url, body = request$values, encode = request$encode,  :
>     Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)

What am I doing wrong?

library(rvest):

```
sisben <-html_session("https://wssisbenconsulta.sisben.gov.co/dnp_sisbenconsulta/dnp_sisben_consulta.aspx")

form <- html_form(sisben)[[1]]

fillform <- set_values(form,"ddlTipoDocumento" = "Cédula de Ciudadanía", "tboxNumeroDocumento" = "1234")

sis <- submit_form(session=sisben, form=fillform)
```

Answer (score 0):

What data do you exactly want to scrape? For me the code rather looks as if you interact with a page (fill in a form and submit), but I do not see any rvest code you use to scrape data.

Regarding your error: 
Looking at the html source code it looks like you only submit the label of the "Tipo de Documento", but not the correct internal value (which is numbered)

```
<option value="-1">Seleccione...</option>
<option value="1">C&#233;dula de Ciudadan&#237;a</option>
<option value="3">C&#233;dula de Extranjer&#237;a</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">Registro Civil</option>
<option value="2">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
```

I didn't receive an error using the option value as input:

```
fillform <- set_values(form,"ddlTipoDocumento" = "1", "tboxNumeroDocumento" = "1234")
sis <- submit_form(session=sisben, form=fillform)
```

leads to the output:

> Submitting with 'tboxNumeroDocumento'

Maybe this is already what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Tom. That clear the error. Now I am planning to use sis %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[1]] to extract data.

Comment: and is there a problem with this approach or does it work?

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't produce an error, but are not the fields I was hoping to extract.

Comment: So what does it extract and what did you plan to extract?

Comment: It extracts NA. I was hoping to extract "Puntaje" (score) "Fecha de modificacion" (date),...

Comment: ah I see it's getting more complicated, as it's not a common "Submit" button but one that starts a certain Java action that has to be done. I'll see if I find a way to click it "virtually".

Comment: Thanks Tom, and alternative is to use a "tboxNumeroDocumento" that is not as generic as 1234 so you only get one result. (I dont want to post publicly one of this for privacy reasons). My email santisaap@hotmail.com if you cant guess a random one, and want a real one.

Comment: Unfortunately my attempts haven't been successful yet. Regarding your "generic" (let's call it "dynamic" solution you could just use a loop where you set the parameter iteratively based on a pre-defined input vector, e.g. `tBoxNumbers <- c(n1, n2, n3, n3, ..., nx) | for (i in 1:length(tBoxNumbers) { # <code> # fillform <- set_values(form,"ddlTipoDocumento" = "1", "tboxNumeroDocumento" = tBoxNumbers[i]) # <more code> # }`